# JS script does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is js script on site http://www.partssystem.ru/. This script should move the third block after authorization to the left when changing the resolution in right column, but this does not happen. Address script http://www.partssystem.ru/js/template.js
Sorry for my bad English. Look picture at bottom
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the issue it looks fine to me?

Comment: In general, press ctrl and - and you will see the left part of the "news" will go right. I want this to happen immediately when loading the site. The question is how to do it?

Comment: Try different browsers as I do not see an issue. What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Firefox, Opera, IE, Google Chrome, Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the following code from the `<head>` to just above the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var c = document.id('right_column').getElement('#float_block');
   if (window.getSize().x < 1260 /*|| (c && t > p)*/){
      document.id('float_block').inject(document.id('float_block_default'));
   }
   else{
      if (!c)
         document.id('float_block').inject(document.id('right_column'));
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, now works, but in IE this js code generally ignored and does not work